# How to call javascript function on form_input in codeIgniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

How to call javascript function on form_input() .

```
<?php echo form_input(['name'=>'pwd_length','ng-model'=>'pwd_length','required'=>'required','class'=>'form-control','id'=>'pwd_length','placeholder'=>'Password Length','value'=>set_value('pwd_length')]);?>

function demo()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to array

```
'onclick'=>'function_you_need(\'test\');'
```

Or

```
form_input('name',$value,'onclick="your_function();" class="test" etc');
```

event as you need (onchange, onblur, etc)